# Conversion between Vector3 coordinates and String

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have done the following to save coordinates of bottle in a file.

public class bo : MonoBehaviour {

```
public GameObject[] bottle;
    public void save()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath+"/Info.dat");
    Playerdata data = new Playerdata ();
    data.v[0] = bottle [0].transform.position.ToString();


    bf.Serialize (file,data);
    file.Close ();

}
public void load()
{
    if (File.Exists (Application.persistentDataPath + "/Info.dat")) {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/Initial.dat", FileMode.Open);
        Playerdata data = (Playerdata)bf.Deserialize (file);
        file.Close ();
        Debug.Log("Value "+Vector3FromString(data.x[0]));//line giving runtime error

    }
}

public  Vector3 Vector3FromString(String s)
{
    string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    return new Vector3(
        float.Parse(parts[0]),
        float.Parse(parts[1]),
        float.Parse(parts[2]));
}

[Serializable]
class Playerdata
{
public string v[] = new string[5];
}
```

this line is giving runtime error when method load is called.

```
Debug.Log("Value "+Vector3FromString(data.x[0]));
```

the error shown is :-  FormatException: Unknown char:

Comment: You need to split 's' into substrings using string.Split() then convert each substring to float and set it to corresponding element of vector.

Comment: Could you please write a couple of lines to show how to access individual substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vector serialization functions:

```c#
    public static string Vector3ToString(Vector3 v){ // change 0.00 to 0.0000 or any other precision you desire, i am saving space by using only 2 digits
        return string.Format("{0:0.00},{1:0.00},{2:0.00}", v.x, v.y, v.z);
    }

    public static Vector3 Vector3FromString(String s){
        string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        return new Vector3(
            float.Parse(parts[0]),
            float.Parse(parts[1]),
            float.Parse(parts[2]));
    }
```

Comment: i have changed the serialisable class to the following                                                       
[Serializable]
class Playerdata
{
 public string[] x = new string[6];
}                                                                                                                                     and then I did the following                 bottle[0].transform.position=Vector3FromString(data.x[0]);                                        but it is giving error

Comment: The error showing in this line is:    FormatException: Unknown char:

Comment: I have updated my code as told by you but new error has arised.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 vector = new Vector3( 1,2,3 );
string s = vector.ToString();
string[] subs = s.Split( "(" )[1].Split( ")" )[0].Split ( "," );
Vector3 vector2 = new Vector3( 
    System.Convert.ToSingle( subs[0] ), 
    System.Convert.ToSingle( subs[1] ), 
    System.Convert.ToSingle( subs[2] ) 
);
```